# Hilbert's Syzygy Theorem: Free resolutions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra

I found several different ways to state Hilbert's Syzygy Theorem, one of them being:

> If $k$ is a field, then $R := k[x_1,...,x_n]$ has global dimension $n$, i.e. any $R$-module $M$ has a projective resolution of length at most $n$.

(A proof of this can be found in [Joseph Rotman's book on homological algebra](http://www.math.unam.mx/javier/homologica/rotman.pdf), Theorem 8.37, p.472)

From this it is easy to deduce:

> If $K$ is a field and $R=k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, then every finitely-generated $R$-module $M$ has a free resolution of length at most $n$.

$\Big($Proof: Pick a free resolution $\cdots F_2 \rightarrow F_1 \rightarrow F_0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$ in which each $F_i$ is finitely generated (f.g.). (This resolution exists since every f.g. module is a quotient of a f.g. free module.) As the projective dimension of $M$ is $\leq n$, the $(n-1)^\text{st}$ syzygy of this resolution is projective (Rotman, Proposition 8.6, p.456). Hence there is a projective resolution $0 \rightarrow K_{n-1} \rightarrow F_{n-1} \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow F_1 \rightarrow F_0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$. As $R$ is Noetherian and $M$ is finitely generated, $K_{n-1}$ if f.g. as well. Hence the Quillen-Suslin Theorem (Rotman, Theorem 4.100, p.209) implies that $K_{n-1}$ is free.$\Big)$

$\textbf{My question:}$

Is it necessary to assume that $M$ is $\textit{finitely generated}$ to conclude that it has a free resolution of length at most $n$? All the statements of the theorem that I have seen contain the f.g. assumption (for example on [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/syzygy#hilberts_syzygy_theorem) or [Eisenbud](http://www.msri.org/people/staff/de/ready.pdf) (p.25 of the PDF-file), but I can neither come up with a counterexample for the case when $M$ is not f.g, nor with a free resolution for arbitrarily generated $M$.

Thank you very much!